# Apache chooses wrong version of installed Subversion

Tags: apache-2.2, svn, debian-squeeze

I have a Debian Squeeze server with Apache2 and Subversion on-board. The Subversion version is 1.6.12 (r955767). It is from debian repos. 
But recently I installed Subversion v1.7.7 from sources into /usr/local/
and now in console I see

```
root@test:~# svn --version
svn, version 1.7.7 (r1393599)
   compiled Dec  6 2012, 17:28:19

   ...

root@test:~# svnadmin --version
svnadmin, version 1.7.7 (r1393599)
   compiled Dec  6 2012, 17:28:19

   ...

root@test:~# svnserve --version
svnserve, version 1.7.7 (r1393599)
   compiled Dec  6 2012, 17:28:19

   ...
```

But when I access this server through Apache I'm getting the following server signature

```
Powered by Subversion version 1.6.12 (r955767).
```

Apache virtual host config is

```
<VirtualHost XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:80>
        ServerAdmin aboritskiy@XXXXXXXXX.XX
        ServerName svn.XXXXXXXXX.XX
        HostnameLookups Off
        UseCanonicalName Off
        ServerSignature On

        <IfModule mod_userdir.c>
                UserDir public_html
                Include /etc/apache2/mod_userdir.conf
        </IfModule>
        <Directory "/var/svn/">
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>
        <Location />
                DAV svn
                SVNParentPath /var/svn/repos

                AuthType Basic
                AuthName "Advance Digital Subversion Repository."
                AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/dav_svn.passwd
                Require valid-user
        </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

So the question is:
How does Apache choose the version of Subversion to work with? How to change this setting?

Answer (score 0):

You also need to upgrade the Apache webDav / SVN  module (libapache2-svn) so you'll either need to grab the Apache source as well and compile an updated version of Apache and the lib, else apt-get yourself the latest Apache, SVN and libapache2-svn packages.

Answer (score 0):

If you look in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dav_svn.load`, you'll see

```
LoadModule dav_svn_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule authz_svn_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_authz_svn.so
```

You can confirm that those point to Debian's Subversion 1.6.12 module:

```
$ strings /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_dav_svn.so | grep 'Powered by'
 <hr noshade><em>Powered by <a href="http://subversion.tigris.org/">Subversion</a> version 1.6.12 (r955767).</em>
```

You should modify `/etc/apache2/mods-available/dav_svn.load` to point to your self-built Subversion modules for Apache.